# how to send the contact form details to your mail id using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Help me out friends i have been working form 14 days on the word press and could not able to send the contact form details to the mail id from the contact form to the mail

Comment: Add some more details..any code you are using to send mail or which plugin you are using.

Comment: Without Code there is not much we can do to help you. You could also try using a simple free plugin to do the trick for you: http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: contact form 7 only as a plugin my word press but when we enter the submit button it is showing the error while submit is clicked that too i have no idea about the programming part in word press plz help out

Answer (score 0):

I assume u entered the right e-mail adress in ur settings.

Are you hosting your website on a localhost? then u can find you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/2753684)

Hope that helps